# streaming file sink : track when a part file is finished

Tags: apache-flink

I have job that writes records to a remote file system using StreamingFileSink. I would like to build an index of which part file contains a record. Is there a way to achieve this using Flink APIs ? Or is there a way to know that a part file is finished and I can now process it offline for indexing ?

Answer (score 0):

In the daily build of the Flink documentation, the [part file lifecycle](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#part-file-lifecycle) of the StreamingFileSink is described in detail.

The short answer is that the part files are renamed when they can safely be consumed -- "safely" meaning that the file has been closed (no further writes will occur) and checkpointed. At this point the filename will change from `part-subtaskIndex-partFileIndex.inprogress.uid` to `part-subtaskIndex-partFileIndex`. For example, the name might change from `part-1-0.inprogress.ea65a428-a1d0-4a0b-bbc5-7a436a75e575` to `part-1-0`.

Note that having checkpointing enabled is required for correct operation of the StreamingFileSink.

Coming back to the first part of your question -- can you determine which part file contains a given record, using the public API? I believe that is done by [KeyGroupRangeAssignment.assignKeyToParallelOperator](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.9/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/state/KeyGroupRangeAssignment.java#L48).

For an explanation of how keyed state is organized, see [A Deep Dive into Rescalable State in Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/features/2017/07/04/flink-rescalable-state.html).

Comment: Thanks David. This is very helpful appreciate it!